# Scipy Minimize: minimize a function over a set of data

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, minimize

I am a very new student to both machine learning and python. I got a question when I was trying to minimize my Expected Improvement function. The purpose of minimize EI function is to predict next best X. How can I make it to choose the X in my data set?

For example, x-axis of my data set looks like (0,1,0.2,0.4,0.8,..2.4,2.6), for now my code will predict X at any point in a range such as 0.382727 which I don't have in my data set and don't have a y-value for it.

What should I do in my case? Is it possible to use constraints scipy.minimize to fix this problem or do you have any other suggestion for me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Could you provide some sample data to better understand your inputs and the desired output? Also try to explain further when you want to minimize what objective function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Say that I have a data set like array = np. array([[0.1,2.1],[0.2,3.1],[0.3,4.2],.....,[1.2,4.5],.....[3.8,3.2]]) where the first column is x-input and the second column is y-output. I trained a gaussian process model with 5 of these data. Now I want to use bayesian optimization(acquisition function is EI) to predict a x belonging to my data set which tends to get the maximum of y=output. When I use scipy.minimize, it returns a res.x that is not belong to my data set like res.x = 1.39482. Is there any way that I can make it to choose the next best x in my data set?